# Do we need [seeeduino]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

Today I have found out about [seeeduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seeeduino) tag existence. There is no wiki on this tag.

This tag has only three questions, one is currently closed as general computing. The other two seem to not need that tag anyway - both are also tagged with [arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arduino).

Is there any reason to keep this tag, or should it be just burninated?

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   - It does somewhat describe the contents of a question, but it does so ambiguously. The lack of any usage guidance or information on the tag makes it difficult to understand when to use this tag.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   - I'd say not really. Seeeduino itself is just a development board.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   - No. Each (on-topic) question with this tag is also tagged with [arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arduino). From description of the board: *Seeeduino v4.2 is based on the Arduino Uno bootloader*.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   - Yes.

Comment: As this tag appears to merely refer to a particular brand of arduino, I've taken the liberty of removing all three occurrences of the tag.  Problem solved.

Comment: Same category as [banana-pi], [odroid], [beagleboard], [orange-pi], along with bigger cousins [android] and [raspberry-pi].  [seeeduino] is **not** an Arduino brand, it merely claims to be compatible.  When is that ever true.

Comment: To be fair, [raspberry-pi] doesn't have much in common with [arduino].

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not true. They are both mini computers, they are somewhat compatible with each other.... what else? I have a raspberry pi and 10 arduinos and they have a lot in similar.

Answer (score 15):

I strongly believe that this burnination was **a *major* mistake**.

There is absolutely nothing wrong with having a tag for a specific type of development board. In fact, that's about as good a use of a tag as I can think of, save perhaps for a tag corresponding to a specific programming language.

Seeeduino is, indeed, an Arduino-compatible board. Although it aims for 100% compatibility, that doesn't mean that such compatibility has been achieved. As [Hans Passant notes in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404017/do-we-need-seeeduino#comment816356_404017):

> Same category as [banana-pi], [odroid], [beagleboard], [orange-pi], along with bigger cousins [android] and [raspberry-pi].  [seeeduino] is **not** an Arduino brand, it merely claims to be compatible.  When is that ever true.

And even if the manufacturer has managed to achieve 100% Arduino-compatibility, that doesn't mean there can't still be Seeeduino-specific questions, making this a useful tool for categorization.

The fact that you only managed to find off-topic questions doesn't mean that the tag is unsuitable for Stack Overflow. It just means that the off-topic questions need to be closed.

You claim that the tag is "ambiguous", but provide no evidence for that outlandish claim. In fact, there's nothing ambiguous about it. It is about as specific and obvious as it can be: it is for programming questions about the specific development board, Seeeduino. What could possibly be clearer?

The fact that a tag wiki is not well written is not and has never been a reason to remove a tag. A large number of tag wikis on Stack Overflow are poorly written and provide almost no usage guidance for the tag. But it would be counter-produce to remove the entire tag on this basis. Someone who knows what the tag is about could just write a tag wiki, and the problem resolves itself.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
>
> I'd say not really. Seeeduino itself is just a development board.

Yes, exactly—it's a development board. That is, a piece of hardware that programmers use to do…*development*. How is that off-topic for a Q&A site on software development, again?

**Please avoid burninating tags where you have no subject-matter expertise whatsoever. This should reduce your chances of making the site a worse place, due to your limited knowledge and inability to understand the work that other software developers do.** Not everyone is a web developer.

Comment: I have checked out all three questions, then asked in SOCVR, with not much reply but there were thoughts that it is useless tag. As my expertise in this tag is zero, I have rised a question if this tag was needed with my (not necessarily correct) observations. The tag was burninated few mins after posting without any discussion, thus there was not much space for deciding if the tag is useful. In that sense you can be fully correct. Also I am just a human that always can be incorrect, thats why there should always be a discussion about such actions.

Comment: @Ruli  You did, indeed, ask in SOCVR, but you posted this burnination request about 1.5 hours later. That's not nearly enough time to wait for people to respond to you in chat, *especially* considering that Dec 25th was a holiday in many parts of the world. But my principal gripe is not with you. It's with whoever the cowboy was that decided merely seeing this burnination request posted gave them the clearance to unilaterally destroy a tag. This is a big problem with *any* burnination requests that are posted on MSO. I have no good way of stopping people from doing this.

Comment: I value your feedback much, this is a lesson to not use the burnination tag if not entirely sure for future. I rather could only rise discussion.

Comment: [shrug] It was **three tag instances,** and I have editing privileges.  Someone can resurrect the tag if they really want it.  I wouldn't exactly call it a "burnination."  Waiting until a tag has three hundred instances makes removal much more difficult.

Comment: I've reverted my changes.  Next time, instead of calling people cowboys and accusing them of ignorance, why don't you just ask?  We can have a *nice* conversation.

Comment: I agree with most of your answer except the last part.... there are many burnination requests that have been carried out by people who don't know anything about the subject at hand. I just don't see the need to be an SME when burninating. Just do research about the tag and see what contexts it can be understood in.

Comment: I call it like I see it, @Robert. I know that isn't a foreign concept to you. This isn't a place to ask or have a discussion with individuals.

Comment: @10Rep You don't have to be a subject matter expert to *participate*. You need to be one to decide to *initiate*, or you need to at least consult one when deciding to initiate. In our burnination process, the actual removal of the tag doesn't begin until a consensus is reached, which requires involvement from people with expertise. This case actually falls into an exception for the standard burnination process, since there were so few questions with that tag. I created that exception, and I meant *only* for it to apply to people with relevant expertise, so things like this don't happen.

Comment: @CodyGray: You're welcome.